# Rerender Function Component on Object Attribute change

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function component

```
function FunctionComponent(propObject: {first: string, second: {})
```

I have it linked as a React Element

```
render() {
  ..
  let obj = {}
  <FunctionComponent
    propObject={{
    first: "STRING"
    second: obj}} />
```

During the course of using the component on the page, the propObject will be changing 'first' and 'second' values. Since the checker does a shallow comparison, it does not see that an attribute has changed in the object prop. Is there a Hook or some other technique to either do a deep check?

Comment: from the little you gave... I'm guessing the string wont be a problem. the obj on the other hand... if you're using `let`... are you updating it directly? if you put it inside a `useState` and use the setState to change states... it wont give you problems

Comment: The destructuring in your component is missing curlies. (A pair around the entire argument and another closing one at the end.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react the common approach when you change deeply nested value is to change simultaneously all affected container objects (or arrays). For example if your `second` prop has structure as follows:

```js
const oldProp = {
    a: { 
        b: { c: 'some-value-c', d: 'some-value-d' }, 
        e: { f: 'some-value-f' },
    },
    g: { h: 'another-value' },
    i: 'yet-another-value',
}
```

and you need to change the value of `a.b.c` property you have to create new references along the way for all enclosing object: root, `a`, `b`. But leave intact all other objects. To not trigger unnecessary rerenders if any of your other components depend on those objects.

So the update may look like:

```js
const oldProp = {
    a: { 
        b: { c: 'some-value-c', d: 'some-value-d' }, 
        e: { f: 'some-value-f' },
    },
    g: { h: 'another-value' },
    i: 'yet-another-value',
}

// updating value of `a.b.c` field

const newProp = {
    ...oldProp,
    a: {
        ...oldProp.a,
        b: {
            ...oldProp.a.b,
            c: 'changed-value-c'
        }
    }   
}

console.log('updated prop', newProp)

console.log('old === new', oldProp === newProp)
console.log('old.a === new.a', oldProp.a === newProp.a)
console.log('old.a.b === new.a.b', oldProp.a.b === newProp.a.b)
console.log('old.a.e === new.a.e', oldProp.a.e === newProp.a.e)
console.log('old.g === new.g', oldProp.g === newProp.g)
console.log('old.i === new.i', oldProp.i === newProp.i)
```

As you may notice, the only object got updated references are the ones that were met along the way to the `a.b.c` property. All the other kept referencial equality.

Updating deeply nested object can get messy pretty fast. Fortunately there are a lot of packages solving that kind of problems. [`Ramda`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ramda) for example. The above example will look like:

```js
const oldProp = {
    a: { 
        b: { c: 'some-value-c', d: 'some-value-d' }, 
        e: { f: 'some-value-f' },
    },
    g: { h: 'another-value' },
    i: 'yet-another-value',
}

// updating value of `a.b.c` field

const newProp = R.assocPath(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'changed-value-c', oldProp)

console.log('updated prop', newProp)

console.log('old === new', oldProp === newProp)
console.log('old.a === new.a', oldProp.a === newProp.a)
console.log('old.a.b === new.a.b', oldProp.a.b === newProp.a.b)
console.log('old.a.e === new.a.e', oldProp.a.e === newProp.a.e)
console.log('old.g === new.g', oldProp.g === newProp.g)
console.log('old.i === new.i', oldProp.i === newProp.i)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

If deep update with updating references is not an option you can resort to the [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for functional components or [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method for class components for fine tuning your reder logic. The former accepts equality check function as a second argument where you can perform your computations. The latter accepts `nextProps` and `nextState` arguments you can compare with `this.props` and `this.state` correspondingly to make a decision on whether to rerender you component or not.

That usually is less preferred way as it may lead to unexpected behavior when something changes in other parts of application and your equality checker gets out of sync with those changes.